# EE Calendar Not Displaying Custom Fields Inside Channel Entries

Tags: ee2, solspace-calendar

I am trying to setup some templates to use the EE Calendar module from Solspace. I am calling the calendar data with {exp:calendar:cal and I get my event custom field no problem with this is by itself.  If I nest this {exp:calendar:cal inside a exp:channel:entries tag or structure:entries tag I lose the custom field.  Basically something like this

> {exp:channel:entries disable="member_data|categories|category_fields" >require_entry="yes"} 
>   {exp:calendar:cal  backspace="3" date_range_start="year-month-01" >date_range_end="3 months"}

Dropping the exp:channel:entries line it works, but I need data from that since I am trying to integrate calendar data in an existing template.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the calendar bit as an embedded template.

Comment: This is basically what I did.  For anyone else that might run into this, we use Structure as well.  If you change months with the calendar it passes it through the url.  Changing the url breaks Structure.  What we ended up doing was using a jquery based calendar for the UI and use the calendar to serve up the data only.  I have to specify a range to preload to be able to browse months but embedding the calendar module works like a champ when serving up data.  Standalone I wouldn't be able to load the next month.  Thanks for your help.